# How to show progress indicator or progress Bar in the titleBar in android?

Tags: android

I have an http request and some UI change during that time and I want to show the activity indicator during that time . I want to show it in the title bar.
I want to show progress indicator in the title in android like activity  indicator in iphone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your activity code:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
...
// when you need to show progress:
setProgressBarIndeterminate([true|false]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, above two/three lines need to be used in following way.

1) Need to add this **before** calling setContentView() method.

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

2) Need to add this **after** calling setContentView() method.

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

To stop the progress indicator

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

If we start showing progress from a parent activity and closing from a child activity,

```
ParentActivity parent = (ParentActivity)getParent();
parent.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```